# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my application was working fine until I tried to add "add to cart" functionality. I am trying to fetch products from backend API and display it into my app (which worked fine previously) and add to cart functionality where users can click add to cart and it adds the specific product into their localstorage but I get `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` error when I simply load up the page. Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import axios from 'axios'


function HomeScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    function handleClick(product) {
        setCart(cart + product)
        localStorage.setItem("cartItems", cart)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getProducts() {
            try {
              const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products/');
              setProducts(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
          }
       getProducts()
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map(product => (
                <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded" key={product.id}>
            <Card.Img src={'http://localhost:8000' + product.image} />
            <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{product.name}</strong>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text as="div">
            
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Text as="h3">
            ${product.price}
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Link>
                <Button onClick={handleClick(product)} className="btn-primary">Add to cart</Button>
            </Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: `onClick={handleClick(product)} ` should be `onClick={()=>handleClick(product)} `

Answer (score 3):

```
onClick={()=>handleClick(product)}
```

Passing the handleClick function to onClick actually runs it causing a re-render everytime the Button is rendered.

Passing it as a arrow function, passes the function object without executing it, until the onClick method is called.